# SQL Server 2008 - ROWNUMBER OVER - filtering the result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I have the following SQL which works and returns products with duplicate names and the rownum column is a count of how many times that name appears.

Adding `where rownum > 1` at the end gives me the duplicates only.

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    (SELECT
         id, productname,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY productname 
                            ORDER BY productname) Rownum
     FROM products 
     GROUP BY id, productname) result
```

**REQUIREMENT**

I need to produce a list of products where if the rownum column has a value greater than one, I want to see all the rows pertaining to that product grouped by the name column.

If the rownum value for a product is 1 only, and no value greater than one (so no duplicate) I don't want to see that row.

So for example if "Blue umbrella" appears three times, I want to see the result for this product as:

```
ID  Name           Rownum
35  Blue umbrella   1
41  Blue umbrella   2
90  Blue umbrella   3
```

How would I go about achieving this please?

Comment: Actually what's your expected output? Only need to show the row with `rownum=1`?

Comment: hi, no if any row has a number greater than 1 in the rownum column, eg 3, i want to see the other two related rows as well. so  basically i want to see all duplicates next to each other. i hope that clarifies it

Answer (score 2):

Change the `Row_NUmber Over to Count(1) Over` and `select where the count is greater than 1` and remove the group by

```
SELECT * from (Select id,productname,
        Count(1) OVER(Partition By productname ORDER by productname) Rownum
            FROM products 
            ) result 
        WHERE Rownum > 1
```

Comment: For readability, probably rename the computed rownum column from rownum to something closer to what it actually contains :)

Comment: i tried this and got the error "The Parallel Data Warehouse (PDW) features are not enabled." :(  but thanks for your response